# How close pipe handle in windows? (fclose() of _pclose())?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, file, pipe

If I create pipe in windows this way:

```
CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, &sec_atr, NULL)
```

Then make `FILE *` from `hRead` this way:

```
int fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hRead, _O_RDONLY|_O_TEXT);
FILE *pipe_read = _fdopen(fd, "rt");
```

Then how should I close this file (`pipe_read`)?

1. `fclose(pipe_read)`
2. `_pclose(pipe_read)`
3. `CloseHandle((HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fileno(pipe_read)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dye30d82%28VS.71%29.aspx), use `fclose`.  The documentation for [fclose](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-us/library/fxfsw25t.aspx) further clarifies with:

> When these functions are used to close a stream, the underlying file descriptor and OS file handle (or socket) are closed, as well as the stream. Thus, if the file was originally opened as a file handle or file descriptor and is closed with fclose, do not also call _close to close the file descriptor; do not call the Win32 function CloseHandle to close the file handle; and do not call closesocket to also close the socket.